# How does the Maya ASCII FBX format store positions within animation?

Tags: animation, maya, file-format, fbx

I want to understand Maya's ASCII FBX format so I can convert animations in it to OSG (OpenSceneGraph) format.

I have a simple sphere, with a translation in one direction for 30 frames baked into an animation. I was expecting to see a list of values like this:

```
Frame #, X-position, Y-position, Z-position
```

However, I find nothing like it in the output file. For example, at frame 1, `X/Y/Z = -7.189/0/10.136`, but I cannot find any of these, or any other `X/Y/Z` position anywhere in the file.

What am I missing?

Could someone point out the frame/xyz position in [the file](http://ge.tt/1Ib7RI22/v/0?c)?

Answer (score 1):

So I found it - posting the response here for future reference

X/Y/Z = -7.189/0/10.136 in the Maya channel editor are rounded off values - the values themselves have a larger number of significant digits - e.g. -7.188707 so search for the first 2 decimal places only